# Collection Cell Index path order grid layout in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have collection view with custom cell currently collection view cell looks

```
0  1
2  3
4  5
```

I need to change the collection view cell order to like

```
0 3
1 4
2 5
```

how can achieve this order?

Comment: Either you modify the collectionView layout, or you modify the datasource, ie the "array" that populate your cells to replicate the order of the elements.

Comment: @Larme Need to create the custom collectionview layout right?